# Do rainwater drain pipes have to bend at the bottom

Tags: drainage, outdoor, downspout

One of our rainwater pipes ends half over a small drain, but the bend at the bottom means some of the water misses the drain and runs off along the patio,

I thought I could simply cut a hole in the bend so the water drops straight down, but does the bend perform any function that would be missed if it was removed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes it stops the water from pooling at the base of the wall and seeping into the foundation

if you can ensure all water goes into the drain there will be no danger though

Comment: Also note that if it's a storm sewer drain, lots of regions no longer allow you to run rainwater through it. (I assume that's not the case in this situation, but FYI for others...)

Comment: What else is a storm drain for if not to catch rainwater?!

Comment: It's usually the sanitary sewer that cannot be tied into for rainwater/groundwater drainage (usually for capacity reasons). The storm sewer, as insta said, is designed for rainwater. If you aren't somehow tying directly into it (i.e. with a weeping system), then you're running it down your driveway into the street where it'll go into a storm drain from there anyway.